# Is "Om Jaya Jagadisha Hare" written for any particular deity?

Tags: aarti, deity

[SOURCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Jai_Jagdish_Hare)

> Om Jai Jagdish Hare (Hindi: ॐ जय जगदीश हरे) is a Hindu religious song. Though it is not written for any particular deity, it is mostly sung in Vishnu temples. Although the religious hymn is a Hindi-language composition, it is widely sung by Hindus. The prayer is sung by the entire congregation at the time of Aarti, a form of Hindu worship.

Comment: Pandit Shardha Ram Phillauri has composed this Aarti to raise the interest of people in bhAgwat kathA.

Comment: I think it is a prayer, to the God(any and all)

Comment: The bigger issue is with Om Jai Shiv Omkara...by this it looks like dedicated to Shiva but when we go on, it compares Trimurti gods...

Comment: @YDS - yes OM Siva Omkara is for the Trimurti.  Also both Hari and Hara ae names of Siva also:(Shiva Ashtottara Sata Namavali)  ōṃ harayē namaḥ
ōṃ pūṣadantabhidē namaḥ
ōṃ avyagrāya namaḥ
ōṃ dakṣādhvaraharāya namaḥ
ōṃ harāya namaḥ (100)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > Does the "*Om Jaya Jagadish Hare*" *aartī*, invokes any particular deity?

Short Answer: Depending on the meaning eschewed from the *aartī* lyrics, **No** & **Yes**.

- ### **The Origin of the *aartī***

The famous *aartī*, "*Jaya Jagadish Hare*", by [Pandit Shardha Ram Phillauri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shardha_Ram_Phillauri), is originally said to have been composed as a Universal *aartī* by the author.
The popular imagination phenomenon might have made it limited to Lord Vishnu.

The *aartī*, as it's sung today might have made its first [raw cinematic appearance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Jai_Jagdish_Hare#Popular_culture) in a song from the 1952 movie, [Anand Math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anand_Math). In here, the [Govinda damodar Stotram](https://saranaagathi.com/govinda-damodara-stotram/) of Sri BilvaMangala Thakura is adapted with the ['Jai Jagdish Hare' refrain](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Jai%20Jagdish%20Hare-Anand%20Math%201952).

The rendition of the written *aartī* reaches its zenith in a later 1970 movie, [Purab Aur Paschim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purab_Aur_Paschim). The [protrayed song in the movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nsPuUXwBI8), playing background of the *aartī*, beautifully portrays the devotion towards the *Radha-Krishna*, and the prayer symbolizes the continuity of the Indian tradition before and after India's independence. This is probably the point which catapulted the song into the popular mass imagination, with it's characteristic background music and tone becoming a favorite *aartī* staple across India (or the hindi speaking belt atleast). This phenomenon is something very similar on the lines of the appearance of *Santoshi Mata* as a mainstream deity due to a [popular bollywood film by the same name.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santoshi_Mata)

The *aartī's* various variations employing same background tune and structure, are used for specific deities such as in: Om Jai Shiv omkara, Om Jai Lakshmi mata, Om Jai Ambe gauri, Om Jai Adya Shakti, Om Jai Saraswati Mata, Om Jai Gange Mata, et al..

- ### For which deity the *aartī* is written ?

  - **View 1: It's not written for Vishnu, but the general Almighty.**

Even if one looks at the wording lyrics of the *aartī*, it specifically doesn't point to a definitive particular deity.
An example -

> ...तुम पूरण परमात्मा, तुम अन्तर्यामी,
> पारब्रह्म परमेश्वर, तुम सब के स्वामी ॥.....
>
> ...Tuma pūraṇa **paramātmā**, tuma **antaryāmī**,
> **PāraBrahma** **parameśvara**, tuma sabkē  svāmī ॥...

Meaning:

> Thou art the **ancient great soul**. Thou art the **omnipotent master Lord**,
> Thou art the **Lord of everything** and
> everyone Oh **Lord of the Universe**

All the known deities within the *Hindu* pantheon have been referred to as by the above epithets in all major works dedicated to them.
And in general, thus, can be used as an *aartī* for all the manifestation of the *Brahman*. Hence, it's actually indeed a Universal *aartī*.

- - **View 2: It's indeed written for Vishnu.**

For example, lets see two lines in the *aartī*

> तुम करुणा के सागर, **तुम पालनकर्ता**,...
>
> Tuma karuṇā ke sāgara, **tuma PālanaKartā**...

Meaning:

> Thou art an ocean of mercy Lord, thou art the protector

Further,

> दीन-बन्धु दुःख-हर्ता, **ठाकुर तुम मेरे**,
>
> dīna-bandhu duḥkha-hartā, **ṭhākura tuma mere**

Meaning:

> Friend of the helpless and feeble Lord, you are my overlord or thakur
> ji (*Shri Krishna*)

Generally, it's a common *paurāṇika* tradtion (across all *sampradāyas*) to specifically refer Lord *Vishnu* as the *PālanaKartā* of the Universe. Further, the epithet *ṭhākura ji*, is quite a prevalent name for *Vishnu* in his *Shri Krishna avatara*.

Moreover, the word "Hare" (हरे) can be interpreted as either the vocative form ( [सम्बोधन विभक्ति : sambodhana vibhakti](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case#Sanskrit) ) of Hari, which is another name of *Vishnu*, meaning "he who removes illusion". Another interpretation is as the vocative of Harā, becoming *Hare*, which is a name of Rādhā. In any case the case is made for the *aartī* to be Vishnu centric, in this case.

Thus, by the above explained logic, it **maybe** argued that indeed, the *aartī* is in reverence to *Vishnu* only.

### Conclusion:

Thus, depending on how the lyrics are analysed, one maybe to able to reach both the conclusion that

- Yes, indeed the *aartī* is for *Vishnu*

and/or

- No, the *aartī* is for the the general Almighty, *Brahman* and hence can be used for any *saguṇa* or *nirguṇa* form of the Supreme.

Comment: May have not read properly but you can also add: Jagadish **Hare**. Hare = sambodhan form of Hari which is Bhagwan Vishnu’s name

Comment: @Vivikta When you want to address Hari, the word becomes Hare! Which is, "Oh Hari!"

Comment: @Surya, thanks!

Comment: Sanskrit has no proper nouns.  It is a fairly long poem and strictly stays away from specifying the deity being prayed to. It is praying to Ishwara @vivikta

Comment: @SK True in a broad perspective, it doesn't refer to a particular form of the Lord.

Comment: Those who state that this song addresses Parabrahman are overlooking the fact that the song addresses a male divinity, whereas Brahman is genderless.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent answer from Vivikta - just adding two small items of evidence that this is for Ishwara or Trimurti and not any particular deity:

the deity is called parameshwar in addition to Hari - Parameshwar is usually Siva (not always, though).  And Hari is also a name of Siva:

https://vignanam.org/english/shiva-ashtottara-sata-namavali.html

विषय-विकार मिटाओ, पाप हरो देवा
(स्वामी, पाप हरो देवा)

It uses "har" as a verb - "destroy my sins" - Hara (noun) is Siva.

Magnificent prayer - an essence of Hinduism.