# The Source Scripture of Popular Lakshmi Aarti

Tags: lakshmi, aarti

This is the popular and most common aarti (devotional song) of goddess Lakshmi.[Ma Lakshmi aarti](https://www.livehindustan.com/astrology/story-diwali-maa-lakshmi-aarti-read-here-the-maa-lakshmi-aarti-laxmi-aarti-lyrics-in-hindi-2813538.html) and [here](https://jaihinduism.com/lakshmi-maiya-ki-aarti/)

What is the Scriptural source of this song?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Any kind of *Āartís*, or  *Chālīsā* which we use presently, is a modern-day work**, starting with the oldest known & composed "Universal Āartí" - i.e., Om Jaya Jagadiśh Hare, about which I have discussed in detail in [this Answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45546/is-om-jaya-jagadisha-hare-written-for-any-particular-deity/45556#45556)

All the presently known and sung Āartís (like Om Jai Shiva Omkārā, Om Jai Ambe Gaurí, Om Jai Ādyā Shakti, Om Jai Saraswatí Mātā, etc.) are the [descendants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arti_(Hinduism)#Arti_songs) of the "Om Jaya Jagadish Hare" āarti only, which is very evident from the lyrics, compositions, and the tonal setting of the composition. So basically almost all the presently used āartis are the "deity-specific" variation-versions of the Om Jaya Jagadish Hare only.

And the same goes for the āarti - Om Jai Lakshmí Mātā, asked in the question. **Therefore, there is no scriptural source for any āartí including the "Maa Lakshmi Song - Om Jai Lakshmí Mātā". All the currently known and used *āartis* are present-day "Modern Works" unrelated with any canonical texts or scriptures**

"*How much or why they're considered effective on a spiritual or theological perspective level when compared to the Stotras or Mantras found in the canonical texts,*" that is something we don't know on definite terms. And that's why I have asked this question: [What gives the “spiritual - theological authenticity” to modern compositions like Chālīsās & āartís?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45381/what-gives-the-spiritual-theological-authenticity-to-modern-compositions-lik)